# sizeof operator returns 4 for (char + short )

Tags: c

Given this code snippet:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

        short i = 20;
        char c = 97;

        printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sizeof(i), sizeof(c), sizeof(c + i));

        return 0;
    }
```

Why is `sizeof(c + i) == 4`?

Comment: Integer promotion?

Comment: (c+i) is added first and the sizeof is calculated for the resultant.. and the result is an integer.. so size is 4..

Comment: Nitpick: `sizeof` is not a function, it's an operator.

Comment: Remember: `sizeof()` is compilation time operator, type of expression is known at compilation time, arithmetic types of operations in C require two operands to be converted to a common type --referred to as the integral promotions,

Comment: @RaghuSrikanthReddy: No addition is performed. `sizeof` is operated at compile time except the exception in case of VLAs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`c + i` is an integer expression (integer promotion!), so `sizeof()` returns `sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 5):

> Integer types smaller than int are promoted when an operation is
>   performed on them. If all values of the original type can be
>   represented as an int, the value of the smaller type is converted to
>   an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.

Integer promotions require the promotion of each variable (c and i) to int size.

```
short i = 20;
char c = 97;  
//The two int values are added and the sum is truncated to fit into the char type.
char a = c + i;
printf("%d, %d, %d %d\n", sizeof(i), sizeof(c), sizeof(c + i),sizeof(a));  

2, 1, 4 1
```

Comment: Interesting Chapter sharing with you [Operator Conversions: Arithmetic Conversions](http://csweb.cs.wfu.edu/~torgerse/Kokua/More_SGI/007-0701-150/sgi_html/ch05.html)

Answer (score 3):

The C uses `int` for all integer calculation, if not specified otherwise. On your platform, `int` is clearly 32bit long, so `sizeof` returns `4`. If your compiler would use 64bit integers, it would be `8`.

Comment: a bit of offtopic, but is there any known compiler that uses 64bit ints?

Comment: It's more about the actual architecture - for example SPARC64 - ILP64/SILP64